# Multiword string as a curl option using Bash

Tags: string, bash, curl

I want to get some data from a HTTP server. What it sends me depends on what I put in a POST request.

What I put in the INPUT_TEXT field is a sequence of words. When I run the following command, I get good looking output.

```
$ curl http://localhost:59125/process -d INPUT_TEXT="here are some words"
```

I want a bash script to take some string as a command line argument, and pass it appropriately to curl. The first thing I tried was to put the following in a script:

```
sentence=$1
command="curl http://localhost:59125/process -d INPUT_TEXT=\"${sentence}\""
$command
```

I then run the script like so:

```
$ ./script "here are some words"
```

But then I get a curl `Couldn't resolve host` error for each of "are", "some", and "words". It would seem that "here" got correctly treated as the INPUT_TEXT, but the rest of the words were then considered to be hosts, and not part of the option.

So I tried:

```
command=("curl" "http://localhost:59125/process" "-d" "INPUT_TEXT='$sentence'")
${command[@]}
```

I got the same output as the first script. I finally got what I wanted with:

```
result=$(curl http://localhost:59125/process -d INPUT_TEXT="${sentence}")
echo $result
```

I'm still unsure as to what the distinction is. In the first two cases, when I echoed out the contents of command, I get exactly what I input from the interactive Bash prompt, which had worked fine. What caused the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work:

```
command=("curl" "http://localhost:59125/process"
         "-d"  "INPUT_TEXT=$sentence")
"${command[@]}"
```

That has two changes from yours:

- I removed the incorrect quotes around `$sentence` since you don't want to send quotes to the server (as far as I can see).
- I put double-quotes around the use of `"${command[@]}"`. Without the double quotes, the array's elements are concatenated with spaces between them and then the result is word-split. With double quotes, the individual array elements are used as individual words.

The second point is well-explained in the [bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and a bunch of SO answers dealing with quotes.

The important thing to understand is that quotes only quote when a command is parsed. A quote which is a character in a variable is *just a character*; it is not reinterpreted when the value of the variable expanded. Whitespace in the variable is used for word-splitting if the variable expansion is unquoted; the fact that the whitespace was quoted in the the command which defined the variable is completely irrelevant. In this sense, bash is just the same as *any other programming language*.